# image database for segmentation

Tags: image

Is there any good database of images with their ground truths online that I can use to perform image segmentation tests?

Comment: You'll have to expand the question to clarify what *ground truth* and *image segmentation* mean.

Comment: @wallyk, somebody who doesn't even know what those widespread terms of art mean may be somewhat unlikely to know about good datasets related to them, so I think it's reasonable on the OP's part to skip defining the terms;-).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is [bsds](http://www.eecs.berkeley.edu/Research/Projects/CS/vision/bsds/) what you're looking for?  It's about 50 MB and the conditions seem good:

> You are free to download a portion of
>   the dataset for non-commercial
>   research and educational purposes.  In
>   exchange, we request only that you
>   make available to us the results of
>   running your segmentation or boundary
>   detection algorithm on the test set as
>   described below.

Comment: I am looking for ground truths in which each pixel is given a color according to their segment, from what I understand this has to be done by hand to be very precise. I guess I can probably modify the bsds segments for use like that but not sure if it will be very accurate. Are there any other databases you know of, google does not turn up anything good.